# Grails NPE on root context?

Tags: grails, model-view-controller, nullpointerexception, gsp

My Grails (2.4.2) project's basic structure:

```
my-app/
    grails-app/
        views/
            web/
                index.gsp
                signin.gsp
            admin/
            app/
        controllers/
            myapp/
                WebController.groovy
    <rest of project is a normal Grails app>
```

My `application.properties`:

```
#Grails Metadata file
#Thu Nov 06 14:21:10 EST 2014
app.grails.version=2.4.2
app.name=my-app
app.context=/
app.version=0.1
```

My `UrlMappings`:

```
class UrlMappings {
    static mappings = {
        "/$controller/$action?/$id?(.$format)?"{
            constraints {
                // apply constraints here
            }
        }

        "/"(controller: "web")
    }
}
```

My `WebController`:

```
package myapp

class WebController {
    def index() {
        render(view: "web/index")
    }

    def signin() {
        render(view: "web/signin")
    }
}
```

When I `run-app`:

```
|Loading Grails 2.4.2
|Configuring classpath
.
|Environment set to development
.................................
|Packaging Grails application
....................................
|Running Grails application
|Server running. Browse to http://localhost:8080/
```

When I click that link (`http://localhost:8080/`):

```
....[ERROR] 2014-11-19 10:22:44,029 org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.errors.GrailsExceptionResolver - NullPointerException occurred when processing request: [GET] /
Stacktrace follows:
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter.doFilter(PageFragmentCachingFilter.java:198)
    at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter.doFilter(AbstractFilter.java:63)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

My intentions are as follows:

- All web pages controlled by the `WebController`
- All web page views stored under `grails-app/views/web`)
- URL mapping such that `http://localhost:8080/` takes you to `grails-app/views/web/index.gsp`
- URL mapping such that `http://localhost:8080/signin` takes you to `grails-app/views/web/signin.gsp`

**What's going on here?**

Comment: You haven't described how you configured the app to be deployed at the root context with the embedded tomcat.  Did you do anything unusual there?

Comment: I see it now in application.properties.  Sorry for the noise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One problem you have is with the following:

```
// ...

render(view: "web/index")

// ...

render(view: "web/signin")

// ...
```

The problem with those is you are specifying a relative path.  It will be relative to `grails-app/views/web/` since you are in the `Web` controller.  You could make them absolute like this...

```
// ...

render(view: "/web/index")

// ...

render(view: "/web/signin")

// ...
```

But the more common thing to do is allow them to be relative like this...

```
// ...

render(view: "index")

// ...

render(view: "signin")

// ...
```

Comment: Thanks @Jeff Scott Brown (+1) - both suggested changes have the same effect: I stop seeing errors, but going to the URLs produces a blank/empty page.  I would *prefer* to use absolute URLs like (`/web/index`) because I may have multiple GSPs with the same name, but this is not a hard requirement. Either way, although your suggestions made the error stop, I'm still unable to see my pages when I go to their respective URLs. Any ideas? Thanks again!

Comment: See https://github.com/jeffbrown/webroot.  When I run that and send a request to the root (http://localhost:8080/), it works.

Comment: "I would prefer to use absolute URLs like (/web/index) because I may have multiple GSPs with the same name" - You could have dozens of GSPs with the same name and still use relative URLs.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you again @Jeff Scott Brown (+2 for both), I needed to restart Grails for some reason. Last follow up question: I see in your `UrlMappings` you explicitly define "`"/signin"(controller: 'web', action: 'signin')`"... **is there any way to do away with this?** I would hope that the mapping would work without this entry, because in the `WebController` I am explicitly rendering the `signin` view when the `signin` action is executed. Any ideas? Thanks again!

Comment: "is there any way to do away with this" - That really depends on clarification of what you mean by "this".  If you don't have a mapping which leads to the controller, it won't matter what code is in the controller.  It seems that one of us is confused about the fundamentals of how this works.

Comment: Are you looking for something like this: https://github.com/jeffbrown/webroot/commit/3aeaeb6bafeb6c2563640c59668dca9cf1502cba

Comment: See https://github.com/grails-samples/grails-website/blob/master/grails-app/conf/UrlMappings.groovy as an example.  That is the url mappings for the app which runs http://grails.org/.

Comment: Thanks again @Jeff Scott Brown (+3 for all) - I guess I'm looking to tell Grails "Hey, treat the root context "`/`" as the `WebController`, and any actions directly off of it (such as `/signin`, `/aboutUs`, `/contact`) as `WebController` actions." But maybe this is all complicated by the fact that I'm using a root context instead of convention (such as `/web/signin`), etc. Thoughts?

Comment: Are you wanting something like `"/$action?"(controller: "web")`?

Comment: See https://github.com/jeffbrown/webroot/commit/d066c3246fcd1a367ca8575fd973580039e1512a.  I am afraid I can't be of any more help.  Best of luck with it.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was

```
render(view: 'myview')
```

But needed

```
render(template: 'myview')
```